# Hide legend numbers in Google Geocharts

Tags: google-maps, charts, google-visualization

Is there a way to hide the numbers in the legend in Google geocharts?
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

I see a few options to style the legend and the number format but not a way to hide the numbers in the legend. When I use legend: 'none', it hides the whole legend which I don't want.

I tried to run this jquery as well after the chart loads but upon hovering over the map, it brings the legend numbers back.

```
$("text[text-anchor='start']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple options...

1. Set `legend.textStyle.color` to the same color as the background...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, {
      legend: {
        textStyle: {
          color: '#ffffff'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

2. Since the labels re-appear on any interactivity,
   use a `MutationObserver` to know when activity has occurred,
   then remove or hide the labels...

the only hurdle is not removing other labels in the chart, such as on the tooltips

see following working snippet, a unique color is given to the legend labels for easy identification...

note: when using this approach, the chart will change color names to their hex values, as well as change any letters to lowercase, be sure to start with a lowercase hex value...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

    var labelColor = '#b71c1c';

    var observer = new MutationObserver(removeLabels);
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    function removeLabels() {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(legendLabel) {
        if ((legendLabel.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'start') && ((legendLabel.getAttribute('fill') === labelColor))) {
          legendLabel.parentNode.removeChild(legendLabel);
        }
      });
    }

    chart.draw(data, {
      legend: {
        textStyle: {
          color: labelColor
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```